# RStudio read.xl working directory error

Tags: r, readxl

Hi guys I'm having difficulty loading .xlsx into RStudio - I'm not sure why RStudio can't see the file.
Am I specifying the path for read_excel() wrong?
Any ideas? Pretty new at R.

Thanks!

Windows 10 (64-bit)
Version 0.99.491 & Version 0.99.840
read.xl 0.1.0

`getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/user/Documents/Work"
read_excel(system.file("C:/Users/user/Documents/Work/Data.xlsx"))
Error: '' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/user/Documents/Work')`

Comment: Try loading it with the import data set option.  You can select the file from that.

Answer (score 2):

The results of the system.file command are probably returning a blank character `""`:

```
system.file("C:/Users/user/Documents/Work/Data.xlsx")  
[1] ""
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. Instead, just try specifying the full path within the excel_sheets function, i.e.,

```
read_excel("C:/Users/user/Documents/Work/Data.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `paste0` function:

```
read_excel(paste0(getwd(), "/Data.xlsx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you save the file? Is the file saved as Data.xlsx? If so, please remove the extension .xlsx and then try to import with read_excel("Data.xlsx"). I faced the similar error and after removing the extension, it worked fine.