# R Shiny not reading file path

Tags: r, shiny, readxl

Consider a shiny app with the following folder structure (github [here](https://github.com/peterparkerspicklepatch/opensource-freetoplay-economics)):

```
├── data
│   └── import_finance.R
│   └── data.xlsx
├── dashboard.R
├── ui_elements
│   └── sidebar.R
│   └── body.R
```

The `import_finance.R` runs correctly when not run in the shiny app. However, when running the shiny app it fails to recognize the path.

```
# list of quarterly earnings worksheets
file_paths <- list.files('dashboard/data', pattern = 'xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
path <- file_paths[1]


# import all sheets from each workbook and merge to one df

 import <-
  path %>%
  excel_sheets() %>%
  set_names() %>%
  map_df(xlsx_cells, path = path) %>%
  mutate(workbook = word(path, -1, sep = '/')) # add column with file_name
```

Shiny says `Error: path does not exist: ‘NA’`. Please note that `import_finance.R` is called in `dashboard.R` via `source("data/import_finance.R")`.

Even when specifying the full path the error persists. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557318/rstudio-read-xl-working-directory-error) claims the same error:

```
> system.file("/Users/pblack/Documents/Git Projects/opensource-freetoplay-economics/dashboard/data/dashboard/data/ATVI 12-Quarter Financial Model Q1 CY20a.xlsx")  
[1] ""
```

Any idea of the mistake I'm making? It's strange the script runs fine, but just not when running as a shiny app.

Comment: Try `source("./data/import_finance.R")`

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here was in

```
# list of quarterly earnings worksheets
file_paths <- list.files('dashboard/data', pattern = 'xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
```

When the shiny app was running it was operating from the `data` folder as the working directory *when* running `source("data/import_finance.R")`.

To accommodate simply

```
# list of quarterly earnings worksheets
file_paths <- list.files('data', pattern = 'xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
```